# Add a having condition that makes use of COUNT

Tags: 7, database

I currently have a query that compiles to

```
SELECT n.nid AS nid, field_data_field_date.field_date_value AS incident_date, field_data_field_tweeted_date.field_tweeted_date_value AS tweeted_date, n.nid AS n_nid, (SELECT source.field_source_value AS field_source_value
FROM 
field_data_field_sources sources
left JOIN field_data_field_source source ON source.entity_id = field_sources_value
WHERE  (sources.entity_id = n.nid) 
ORDER BY sources.delta DESC
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0) AS most_recent_source
FROM 
node n
left JOIN field_data_field_incident_type incidenttype ON incidenttype.entity_id = n.nid
left JOIN field_data_field_date field_data_field_date ON field_data_field_date.entity_id = n.nid
left JOIN field_data_field_tweeted_date field_data_field_tweeted_date ON field_data_field_tweeted_date.entity_id = n.nid
WHERE  (n.type = 'incident') AND (n.status = 1) AND( (incidenttype.field_incident_type_tid IN  (9,25)) )
GROUP BY n.nid
ORDER BY field_data_field_date.field_date_value DESC
```

I want to add

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT incidenttype.field_incident_type_tid) = 2
```

And I can get it to work in the query when I manually create it in my SQL gui, but I can't seem to add it to the query in drupal properly.

I added

```
$query->addExpression('HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT incidenttype.field_incident_type_tid) = 2');
```

But that didn't add it how I wanted to the query. The query compiled to

```
SELECT n.nid AS nid, HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT incidenttype.field_incident_type_tid) = 2 
AS expression FROM {node} n left JOIN {field_data_field_incident_type} incidenttype ON incidenttype.entity_id = n.nid 
left JOIN {field_data_field_date} field_data_field_date ON field_data_field_date.entity_id = n.nid 
WHERE (n.type = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (n.status = :db_condition_placeholder_1) AND (n.created < :db_condition_placeholder_2) AND( (incidenttype.field_incident_type_tid 
IN (:db_condition_placeholder_3, :db_condition_placeholder_4)) ) 
GROUP BY n.nid ORDER BY field_data_field_date.field_date_value
```

I'd like to have it between GROUP BY and ORDER BY since that seems to be what worked in the query I manually wrote. Also it added 'AS expression' to the end of it. Is there a way I can specifically add 'HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT incidenttype.field_incident_type_tid) = 2'? Or should I be going about it a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting everything in one expression. I was able to achieve what I needed by creating an alias for the COUNT like so

```
$query->addExpression('COUNT(DISTINCT incidenttype.field_incident_type_tid)','typeCount');
```

and then add a having Condition afterwards using the alias I created like so.

```
$query->addExpression('COUNT(DISTINCT incidenttype.field_incident_type_tid)','typeCount');
```